# Error when using rbt post

Tags: post, encoding, review-board

I am using reviewboard and everytime I try to run the command `rbt post` I receive this error:

> ERROR: Error uploading diff
>
> One or more fields had errors (HTTP 400, API Error 105)
>
> path: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 32746: ordinal not in range(128)

What is the problem?

Comment: I added the `[review-board]` tag. Remember to use relevant tags to make your question easier to find.

Comment: Nobody have this kind of problem?

Comment: I found what cause this error: for those who had some error check repository name in reviewboard to match name from bitbucket